# Bootstrap tour doesn't start until developer console in Chrome has opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to implement a bootstrap tour, but I've run into a caveat. The site im working on uses a script called upfront that changes div ids and classes (its a live webpage editor).

When loading the page I defer my bootstrap tour script so it loads last but when the page has fully loaded the upfront changes don't seem to be detected by my script until I open the dev console. Is there a way in jQuery/JavaScript I can watch the page wait until these upfront changes have been done?

I've tried using a previous's posts attempt to watch for DOM changes (function below):

```
var observeDOM = (function(){
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
        eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

    return function(obj, callback){
        if( MutationObserver ){
            // define a new observer
            var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
                if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
                    callback();
            });
            // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
            obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
        }
        else if( eventListenerSupported ){
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
        }
    };
})();
```

But as this upfront is a live webpage editor software the DOM changes constantly depending on where your mouse is on screen. I set it up so that it would wait and if there were no updates for a duration to run my script but if a user simple moves the mouse it will start the process over which is not what I want.